# Inner Join not using covering index

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

MySQL: 5.7.25-google-log

I'm having a performance problem in my query so I decided to troubleshoot it and I already tried to create several indexes to solve the problem but not entirely sure where about is the problem.

**Problem:**

```
SELECT
  SQL_NO_CACHE order_items.item_id,
  sum(quantity - quantity_arrived) as qty
FROM
  `orders`
  JOIN order_items on order_items.order_id = orders.id
  and `orders`.`type` = ('PurchaseOrder')
  AND `orders`.`buyer_id` = 2790484
  AND (
    order_items.item_id IN (
      SEVERAL ID NUMBERS
    )
  )
  AND (order_items.state IN(1, 5))
  AND (
    order_items.quantity != order_items.quantity_arrived
  )
GROUP BY
  order_items.item_id;
```

**Tables:**

```
CREATE TABLE `orders` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `buyer_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `seller_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
  `type` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 [another columns]


) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=78341044 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
```

```
CREATE TABLE `order_items` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `order_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `item_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `quantity` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `state` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  [another columns]

  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `order_items_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`order_id`) REFERENCES `orders` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=230377675 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

On my explain plan I see only ITEM_ID is used in the index, even though I have a covering index

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: order_items
   partitions: NULL
         type: range
possible_keys: index_order_items_on_item_id_and_order_id_and_state_and_quantity,index_order_items_on_order_id_and_state_and_picked,index_order_items_on_item_id_and_state_and_shipment_id,index_order_items_on_hold_purchase_order_item_id_and_item_id,quantity_queries_on_order_items,orders_items_id,index_order_items_on_state
          key: index_order_items_on_item_id_and_state_and_shipment_id
      key_len: 10
          ref: NULL
         rows: 3029
     filtered: 90.00
        Extra: Using index condition; Using where
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: orders
   partitions: NULL
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,index_orders_on_type_and_seller_id_and_payment_method,index_orders_on_type_and_initiated_by_purchase_order_id,index_orders_on_type_and_seller_id_and_updated_at,index_orders_on_type_and_buyer_id_and_seller_id,index_orders_on_buyer_id_and_seller_id_and_type,index_orders_on_type_and_seller_id_and_buyer_id_and_updated_at,index_orders_on_buyer_id_and_type_id
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: circle_prod.order_items.order_id
         rows: 1
     filtered: 5.00
        Extra: Using where
2 rows in set, 2 warnings (0.14 sec)
```

The first `using where` is caused by `order_items.quantity != order_items.quantity_arrived` the  != signal is a perfomance killer. But why the second query is using where having the index ``index_orders_on_buyer_id_and_type?

EDIT:
As requested

**Indexes:**
Order tables

```
  KEY (`type`,`seller_id`,`payment_method`),
  KEY (`seller_id`,`type`,`any_pending_order_items`,`buyer_id`,`updated_at`),
  KEY (`type`,`initiated_by_purchase_order_id`),
  KEY (`is_transfer`),
  KEY (`type`,`seller_id`,`updated_at`),
  KEY (`type`,`seller_id`,`buyer_id`,`updated_at`),
  KEY (`id`,`buyer_id`,`type`)
```

Order Items

```
  KEY (`order_id`,`state`,`picked`),
  KEY (`back_order_item_id`),
  KEY (`hold_purchase_order_item_id`,`item_id`),
  KEY (`type`,`item_id`,`state`,`quantity`,`quantity_arrived`,`picked`),
  KEY (`type`,`site_id`,`state`),
  KEY (`state`),
  KEY (`item_id`,`state`,`site_id`),
  KEY (`item_id`,`order_id`,`state`,`quantity`),
  KEY (`type`,`item_id`,`state`,`shipment_id`),
  KEY (`item_id`,`invoice_id`),
  KEY (`item_id`,`state`,`site_id`)
  CONSTRAINT `order_items_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`order_id`) REFERENCES `orders` (`id`)
```

I also did a small change in the query and i got some improvement:
on select added the column `order_items.site_id = XXXX` and created the index `` KEY (`item_id`,`state`,`site_id`) ``

Comment: Please clearly list out all indices defined on your tables.

Answer (score 0):

For this query:

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE oi.item_id,
       sum(quantity - quantity_arrived) as qty
FROM orders o JOIN
     order_items oi
     ON oi.order_id = o.id
WHERE o.type = 'PurchaseOrder' AND
      o.buyer_id = 2790484 AND
      oi.item_id IN (SEVERAL ID NUMBERS) AND
      oi.state IN (1, 5) AND
      oi.quantity <> oi.quantity_arrived
GROUP BY oi.item_id;
```

You have two strategies for indexing the query -- and neither gets rid of the `GROUP BY` aggregation which is probably the bulk of the work.  I think the best option is to filter on the `orders` first:

- `orders(type, buyer_id, id)`
- `order_items(order_id, item_id, state, quantity, quantity_arrived)`

Note that the order of the columns in the indexes is important.

Comment: Toss `quantity` from that index; it won't help.  Alternatively, add `quantity_arrived` to make the index 'covering'.

Comment: I already have an index similar to ``orders(type, buyer_id, id)`` but the first collumn isn't ID? since it is used first in the join?

Comment: @MacaulayDiasSouza . . . Putting `id` in that index makes it useless of this query.  But `(buyer_id, type, id)` would work just as well.